# JavaScript function sometimes called, sometimes not

Tags: javascript, function, onload

This looks weird... I have an HTML page in which I can't modify the `"body"` line (because it's php-included from another file). In the file, before the closing `"/body"` tag, I have a JavaScript function:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function doSomething () {
  /* some code */
}
</script>
```

Since I want this function to be executed when the page is displayed, and since I can't modify the "body" line, I added somewhere a small image, and called this function when it loads:

```
<img src="transp.gif" border="0" width="0" height="0" onload="doSomething();" />
```

Problem is the function is sometimes called and sometimes not called. I even verified this with appropriate `"alert"` statement... What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the `"onload"` executing consistently?

Comment: Why not using the right onload? `window.onload = function() { doSomething() };`.

Comment: If the image is in cache I don't think the onload is called. you are better of using one of the suggestions posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you try to call the function before it's in the DOM. Call "DoSomething" after the function is loaded...

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function doSomething () {
  /* some code */
}
doSomething();
</script>
```

But the cleanest solution would be to use:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
   /* some code */
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can the above script containing the `windows.onload` reside within the body section of the HTML?

Comment: sure @FreeBud, but it's window.onload (without the 's') ;-)

Answer (score 3):

you can use event `window.load` that fired when the page (and your img) is loaded

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
   //code
};
</script>
```

and your img without event

```
<img src="transp.gif" border="0" width="0" height="0" />
```

Comment: event listener would be better as it will work even if there's another onload func.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
//your code here
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```